# What would be the best/economical solution to detect an AC device activation?

Tags: power, esp8266

I want to know when a device is turned on/off and generate some statistics.

Microcontroller: ESP8266
AC voltage: 220V

The first thing that came to my mind was using a power consumption sensor which will translate to OFF when consumption = 0 and ON when consumption > 0.

But probably there's a more efficient or economical way to get HIGH/LOW states (3.3v)

TIA

Comment: that depends on the AC device, and the probability of missed activations and false alarms you can accept.

Comment: It should work for all kinds of devices, but I'll start with a motor.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it but I'd be inclined to try a remote current indicator. These are a CT driving an LED and you should be able to either monitor the voltage across the LED or replace it with an opto-isolator giving double isolation between the mains and your microcontroller.

[image]

*Figure 1. A remote current indicator. (Image deviously obfuscated to avoid product recommendations.)*

To increase the sensitivity you wrap multiple turns in the primary of the coil.

Just be careful that the LED in this device isn't a pair of back-to-back LEDs to handle the AC. If you're going the opto-isolator route you could choose one with back-to-back IR LEDs internally.

Comment: I have a similar, non-invasive CT sensor (SCT-13) which I can use with an ADC to get power consumption, but it is something I want to avoid since it's too complicated/expensive for just detecting the start of an electric device.

Comment: Basic current transformer sells for ~US$3 on eBay. eg. https://www.ebay.com/itm/ZMCT103C-5A-5mA-Micro-precision-current-transformer-sensor-ME/174238504434?hash=item28916c95f2:g:yCgAAOSws65eUIan. Use antiparallel silicon diodes as the 'burden' resistor and it will output a 0.6V mains frequency AC square wave with high sensitivity, easy to detect with ADC input.

Answer (score 0):

Check POR (power-on-reset) or UVLO (under voltage lock out) circuits. They are basically the same, just named after a different perspective. All microcontrollers have such a circuitry inside -- though probably not always available -- , but there are dedicated chips to buy as well.

The problem with supply current detection is that you might need to insert a series element (resistor or Hall sensor) and that it might be extremely challenging if not impossible to decide whether the circuit is turned on, just in sleep mode, waiting from an interrupt from a low-power periphery or it is turned-off completely.

If there is no "low voltage" electronic in your load, or it is not accessible, than the above does not help. In theory you can build a voltage divider or a transformer and attach a POR circuit to its output, but I would discourage anybody to tamper with 220V AC directly. 
Hall-sensors are used in DC motors to check their current consumption, so I would look in that direction. You might need a different sensor for different current consumption ranges. (Though this "high-voltage" stuff is not my field of expertise.)

Comment: I think the OP wants to detect mains devices turned on or off. The mention of the ESP device should have been left out as the solution will be pretty much the same for any microcontroller.

Comment: @Transistor. Good point. Seeing the 3.3V and mentioning an uC led me off track.

Comment: Correct. I want to "convert" mains AC voltage to DC 3.3 basically (or HIGH level on the ESP).